# How to make gantt chart view in odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, gantt-chart, odoo-11

Is it possible to make gantt chart view in odoo 11? I try one but it doesn't work.

```
<!-- Gantt View -->
    <record id="view_activity_gantt" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ipss.activity</field>
        <field name="model">ipss.activity</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <gantt date_stop="date_to" date_start="date_from" string="Operations" default_group_by="workcenter_id">
            </gantt>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo support for Gantt Chart Views have been moved to Odoo EE a long time ago. You could use OCA Web Timeline if you are looking for an alternative

https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/web_timeline/

An Example Usage here:

https://github.com/OCA/project/blob/ae2e3ba21bc23f908acd49a62475f1c34d7f303e/project_timeline/views/project_project_view.xml

Comment: You should create another question or an issue for the OCA repository, providing your view

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple subgroups by fields.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell from what I know.